# How to iterate over json output and get the desirable result in dataframe?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am connecting to API & trying to fetch the data. Data extracted in JSON format but I want to convert it into dataframe with certain records. Could you please help me?

Example:

queue_id = 'a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3'

```
queryResult: {'results': [{'data': [{'interval': '2021-10-11T11:46:25.000Z/2021-10-12T11:46:25.000Z',
                        'metrics': [{'metric': 'nOffered',
                                     'qualifier': None,
                                     'stats': {'count': 1,
                                               'count_negative': None,
                                               'count_positive': None,
                                               'current': None,
                                               'denominator': None,
                                               'max': None,
                                               'min': None,
                                               'numerator': None,
                                               'ratio': None,
                                               'sum': None,
                                               'target': None}}],
                        'views': None},
                       {'interval': '2021-10-13T11:46:25.000Z/2021-10-14T11:46:25.000Z',
                        'metrics': [{'metric': 'nOffered',
                                     'qualifier': None,
                                     'stats': {'count': 2,
                                               'count_negative': None,
                                               'count_positive': None,
                                               'current': None,
                                               'denominator': None,
                                               'max': None,
                                               'min': None,
                                               'numerator': None,
                                               'ratio': None,
                                               'sum': None,
                                               'target': None}}],
                        'views': None},
                       {'interval': '2021-10-14T11:46:25.000Z/2021-10-15T11:46:25.000Z',
                        'metrics': [{'metric': 'nOffered',
                                     'qualifier': None,
                                     'stats': {'count': 3,
                                               'count_negative': None,
                                               'count_positive': None,
                                               'current': None,
                                               'denominator': None,
                                               'max': None,
                                               'min': None,
                                               'numerator': None,
                                               'ratio': None,
                                               'sum': None,
                                               'target': None}}],
                        'views': None},
                       {'interval': '2021-10-15T11:46:25.000Z/2021-10-16T11:46:25.000Z',
                        'metrics': [{'metric': 'nOffered',
                                     'qualifier': None,
                                     'stats': {'count': 1,
                                               'count_negative': None,
                                               'count_positive': None,
                                               'current': None,
                                               'denominator': None,
                                               'max': None,
                                               'min': None,
                                               'numerator': None,
                                               'ratio': None,
                                               'sum': None,
                                               'target': None}}],
                        'views': None}],
              'group': {'mediaType': 'voice',
                        'queueId': '73643cff-799b-41ae-9a67-efcf5e593155'}}]}
```

I want result in below format in dataframe-

```
                queue_id            nOffered_count  nOffered_sum       interval_start   interval_end                       
0  a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3   6         None        2021-10-11T11:46:25.000Z  2021-10-12T11:46:25.000Z
1  a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3   1         None        2021-10-12T11:46:25.000Z  2021-10-13T11:46:25.000Z
2  a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3  12         None        2021-10-13T11:46:25.000Z  2021-10-14T11:46:25.000Z
3  a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3   6         None        2021-10-14T11:46:25.000Z  2021-10-15T11:46:25.000Z
4  a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3   6         None        2021-10-15T11:46:25.000Z  2021-10-16T11:46:25.000Z
```

`nOffered_sum` & `nOffered_count` column name is coming like - `metric_sum` & `metric_count`

I tried below code but not giving proper result -

```
        column_names = []
        final_data_lst = []
        
        if(query_result.results != None):
            for item in query_result.results:
                data_lst = []
                for lst_data in item.data:
                    print("####################################")
                    print(lst_data)
                    print("####################################")
                    for met in lst_data.metrics:
                        metric_name = met.metric
                        column_names.append('Queue_Id')
                        column_names.append(metric_name+'_count')
                        column_names.append(metric_name+'_sum')
                        column_names.append('Interval Start')
                        column_names.append('Interval End')
                        data_lst.append(queue_id)
                        data_lst.append(met.stats.count)
                        data_lst.append(met.stats.sum)
                        data_lst.append(lst_data.interval.split('/')[0])
                        data_lst.append(lst_data.interval.split('/')[1])
```

Comment: Values of `nOffered_count` column does not seem to be appear in your json data. How are you calculating that column?

Comment: @MuhammadHassan nOffered_sum & nOffered_count column name is coming like - metric_sum & metric_count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the approaches with the column name as you want:

```
import pandas
from collections import defaultdict
queue_id = 'a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3'
out = defaultdict(list)
for data in queryResult['results']:
    for d in data.get('data'):
        out['queue_id'].append(queue_id)
        for metric in d.get('metrics'):
            out[metric['metric']+"_count"].append(metric['stats']['count'])
            out[metric['metric']+"_sum"].append(metric['stats']['sum'])
        interval = d['interval'].split('/')
        out['interval_start'].append(interval[0])
        out['interval_end'].append(interval[1])

df = pandas.DataFrame(out)
print (df)
```

Comment: 'StatisticalResponse' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Try out the Edited code.

Comment: yes its working.. I have one doubt. This code is working for one queue_id but in actual case it is running for 4 queue_id in a loop. How can I achieve the cumulative result of all the queue_id in a single dataframe.

Comment: if I initialize final_out = [] and then do final_out.append(out), Would it work?

Comment: Are these queue_ids part of the given json?

Comment: BTW if the code works for you, pls feel free to accept it

Comment: queue_id is not part of json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238348/discussion-between-bhagyesh-dudhediya-and-shivika).

Comment: please check the chat.

Comment: Hi Bhagyesh.. If I am changing the json result then this code is not working

Comment: This requires a separate question. The issue mentioned above is solved so can you please raise another for the new issue..?

Answer (score 0):

There were few mistakes in your code to fetch data from JSON but I solved it now you can Try the Below code and let me know if any help is needed.

```
import pandas as pd
queue_id_ls = []
nOffered_count = []
nOffered_sum=[]
interval_start=[]
interval_end=[]
global df1,matric_name

queue_id="qxsdweqe78784"
if(query_result["results"] != None):
  matric_name=query_result["results"][0]["data"][0]["metrics"][0]["metric"]
  df1 = pd.DataFrame({"queue_id":[],
                    matric_name+"_count":[],
                    matric_name+"_sum":[],
                    "interval_start":[],
                    "interval_end":[]})
  for item in query_result["results"]:
    data_lst = []
    for lst_data in item["data"]:
      for met in lst_data["metrics"]:
        metric_name = met["metric"]
        queue_id_ls.append(queue_id)
        nOffered_count.append(met["stats"]["count"])
        nOffered_sum.append(met["stats"]["sum"])
        interval_start.append(lst_data["interval"].split('/')[0])
        interval_end.append(lst_data["interval"].split('/')[1])
df1["queue_id"]=queue_id_ls
df1[matric_name+"_count"]=nOffered_count
df1[matric_name+"sum"]=nOffered_sum
df1["interval_start"]=interval_start
df1["interval_end"]=interval_end

print(df1)
```

Comment: Hi Smit.. Thank for  answer but columns we can't assigned directly. nOffered_sum & nOffered_count column name is coming like - metric_sum & metric_count

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: metric = nOffered so column would be nOffered_sum & nOffered_count.. suppose metric= tacd then columns would be tacd_sum & tacd_count

Comment: Please check the answer I have edited now you can get the dynamic column name.